# Java screen streaming

Tags: java, streaming, screen-capture

I'm trying to stream a part of my Screen to another Computer using Java. I've already tried to use a robot to make Screenshots in an interval controlled by a timer, which worked well. But the Streaming doesn't work well with ImageIO and an Image Stream. There's just a too low Framerate. I've already searched around, but all I could find where similar problems.

My Questions are:

- Is there a library to compress the images created from the robot?
- Has anyone done something like this before?
- Am I doing this completely wrong and there is a better way?

Comment: I tried to do the same. Well, you are just trying to reimplement RDP in java and existing RDP clients such as teamviewer and all use their own proprietary methods for compression.

BTW, don't write the image data to a file, instead, use rasters to access image pixel data and send it over socket. That will be much faster. You can also save the last image into another byte array and send the difference between last value of a pixel to current value of a pixel, that will be faster as the data to send will be less.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying todo what VNC does. See
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing you may look into a VNC implementation for actual code. The compression is not that easy. Since it needs to be fast (relatime) and offer a good compression ratio over slow networks.